# How to calculate with Microsoft Excel the correct amount of minutes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

64 people receive services 105 minutes per day. How can i use Excel to calculate the total minutes of service per day and then multiply by 7, so i have the total amount of minutes per week, and then convert that into hours?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are effectively asking to have he following equation in "Excel-speak". I have found that it is always a good idea to write down the mathematical equation you wish to use, hence:

(64 x 105 x 7)/60

If that is the case, in Excel, always write `=` to start an equation.

For total minutes of service per day, use `*` to multiply two or more variables:

```
=64*105
```

and total amount minutes per week:

```
=64*105*7
```

Then total amount of service hours per week - as you are converting the minutes per week into hours, it is critical to place the `()` around the multiplication you wish to convert.  To convert from minutes to hours, divide by 60, using `/`:

```
=(64*105*7)/60
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to hours, you can use the following formula -

```
=INT(A1/60)&":"&MOD(A1,60)
```

This assumes the total minutes are in cell `A1`

It divides the minutes by 60 to get the number of hours, then has the colon and then the remainder of minutes left after the hours.

So, let's say

- A1 = 64 people
- B1 = 105 hours
- C1 = 7 days
- D1 = `=A1 * B1 * C1` = 47040
- E1 = `=INT(D1/60)":"&MOD(D1,60)` = 784:0

Comment: very nice, I learnt something new!